# Incorrect calculation C uint64_t

Tags: c, vhdl, verilog

Any suggestion why? 
The c-code in different implementations gives a different value(`788f156dbbc97800` or `788f156dbbc87900` see example), manual calculation and implementation on the FPGA gives a "correct" value(`788f156dbbc87900`), but the source software does not require the correct one(`788f156dbbc97800`).
Interested mechanics Occurrences and, if possible, implementation examples Verilog / VHDL

**C  = `788f156dbbc97800`**
 FPGA = `788f156dbbc87900`
 Calc = `788F156DBBC87900`

```
static inline uint64_t rotr64( const uint64_t w, const unsigned c ){
    return ( w >> c ) | ( w << ( 64 - c ) );
}

/*Blake's G function*/
#define G(r,i,a,b,c,d) \
  do { \
    a = a + b; \
    d = rotr64(d ^ a, 32); \
    c = c + d; \
    b = rotr64(b ^ c, 24); \
    a = a + b; \
    d = rotr64(d ^ a, 16); \
    c = c + d; \
    b = rotr64(b ^ c, 63); \
  } while(0)


/*One Round of the Blake's 2 compression function*/
#define ROUND_LYRA(r)  \
    G(r,0,v[ 0],v[ 4],v[ 8],v[12]); \
    G(r,1,v[ 1],v[ 5],v[ 9],v[13]); \
    G(r,2,v[ 2],v[ 6],v[10],v[14]); \
    G(r,3,v[ 3],v[ 7],v[11],v[15]); \
    G(r,4,v[ 0],v[ 5],v[10],v[15]); \
    G(r,5,v[ 1],v[ 6],v[11],v[12]); \
    G(r,6,v[ 2],v[ 7],v[ 8],v[13]); \
    G(r,7,v[ 3],v[ 4],v[ 9],v[14]);


inline static void reducedBlake2bLyra(uint64_t *v) {
    ROUND_LYRA(0);
}


int main()
{
uint64_t *state = malloc(16 * sizeof (uint64_t));

 state[0]  = 0x886405bc4ef729f4;
 state[1]  = 0xeef412028f17fe52;
 state[2]  = 0xc14af5d9d8c1b0d6;
 state[3]  = 0xb4bf0fb0007f7cd8;
 state[4]  = 0x7814c3ff1e1e6584;
 state[5]  = 0x0198a05583c8a31a;
 state[6]  = 0x495a3b6304587341;
 state[7]  = 0x6489e4d1e286df36;
 state[8]  = 0x42c008c5e5f0b5b8;
 state[9]  = 0x81473c472e5c1272;
 state[10] = 0x6ee801e3f691cc77;
 state[11] = 0x3c4a0a05167955f4;
 state[12] = 0x8310219b03708b66;
 state[13] = 0x6bb0801460ab97ea;
 state[14] = 0x13272757d8f7e5fe;
 state[15] = 0x3524a4286f596d06;
    reducedBlake2bLyra(state);

    return 0;
}
```

code example to Play

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2838316d049a2c13 - **788f156dbbc97800**

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92024213ca202525 - **788f156dbbc87900**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different endianness (byte order) in the objects.

In the code at your second link, you define `unsigned long long a = 0xf429f74ebc056488, b = 0x84651e1effc31478;` and add them. Observe that the low bytes `88` and `78` sum to `100`, thus carrying a bit into the next byte, so that `64` and `14` sum to `78`, which becomes `79` when the carry is added. Note that the low byte appears last in this source code.

In the code at your first link, you display the objects byte-by-byte, showing the low bytes first. What the code writes as `f429f74ebc056488` is actually `0x886405bc4ef729f4` in the `uint64_t`, and what it writes as `84651e1effc31478` is actually `0x7814c3ff1e1e6584`.

When you reverse the bytes in the numbers at the second link, the results match the code in the first link.